# Enterprise Messaging API with Web Services for High Performance?

Tags: performance, web-services, soap, jms

Does combining an Enterprise Messaging solution with Web Services result in a real performance gain over simple HTTP requests over sockets?

(if implementation details will help, interested in JMS with a SOAP webservice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as always, it depends. If you are sending xml documents over your socket using the http-protocol, then no.. your performance will be roughly the same as the enterprise frameworks (because, web services are effectively just that, data encoded in the soap protocol, transmitted over the http protocol over a socket).

If you are sending a more lightweight data stream over a socket, then you will probably get better performance.

Ultimately, it depends on what you're sending, how much of it there is, and how often you're sending it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically one uses a messaging solution for message reliability, rather than performance.  If you need guaranteed message delivery, use something like JMS.

HTTP is so lightweight, I can't imagine that any other messaging solution would have higher performance.